# c++ compiler choosing wrong namespace

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I am using the OpenCV library for my project and using namespace "cv" and "std" for my source files.I want to use the string split function to split a string based on a delimiter .But the "split" function is defaulting to the namespace "cv" and is showing errors related to wrong arguments as it is expecting arguments related to the OpenCV slpit function.

What can be done to overcome this problem?I see that the same function worked fine in another source file even though that one has got both std and cv anmespace.

These are the headers I am including in both files -

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream> // for standard I/O
#include <fstream>
#include <string>   // for strings
#include <iomanip>  // for controlling float print precision
#include <sstream>  // string to number conversion
```

Comment: just explicitly use the namespace then...

Comment: I checked and `split` doesn't apear among standard library names.

Comment: @jrok http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3593.html#new_api

Comment: Show me you other file too - or what it #includes and where you call std::split

Comment: Has stdafx.h got boost in?

Comment: No.However I found that the other function also doesn't take it from "std" namespace.As it shows an error when I try using std::split in that file

Comment: I have edited the post to show the definition of the split which is working

Comment: "std::vector>split" ????

Comment: Sorry.That function was defined somewhere and I didn't notice it.I was assuming it's coming from std

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Avoid putting `using namespace std;` and `using namespace cv;` in your code, especially in headers.

If you can't stop yourself, fully qualify the function where you need to, e.g.

```
std::split(...)
```

Comment: i tried that.it shows that namespace std had no member split but it surprisingly works well in my other source file.I am using Visual studio 2010

Comment: See jrok's comment above. There (probably) is no split in std. What is your other function actually #including?

Comment: There is no split in std. There is, however, boost::std

Comment: +1 for avoiding using `using`. It is the single most terrible thing about namespaces in C++. :)

Answer (score 2):

As long as the argument sets for the `cv` and `std` functions are disjoint, you shouldn't introduce any ambiguity in the overload resolution (both would be injected into the global namespace).

Based on a comment showing `split` is from a 2013 proposal much more likely is that your compiler just doesn't implement `std::split` yet.

Comment: you're probably right.when i tried using std::split ,it shows that namespace std had no member split ,but it surprisingly works well in my other source file.I am using Visual studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is prefix the function with its' namespace
For instance

```
std::split(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this by using explicit namespace specifiers.

```
std::split
```